# Android: Not Able to display Offerwall NativeX W3i

Tags: android, connection

I am working on a game - it requires to implement offer-Wall. 
The problem is from within the game I am not able to display the offer-Wall.

My game at the time of loading the splash makes some connections (login, creating sessions etc) with own game server. Once this is done im not able to display the offer-wall.

If I Comment the in-game server connections the offer-wall works good.

And the offe-rwall being used is NativeX (W3i earlier)
But I could display the same offer-wall correctly from another test App.

***Seems like Once the game is connected to the game server, no other connections are alowed Or they are put on hold. Any help with this please.***

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The NativeX MonetizationSDK requires initialization on the UI Thread.

Make sure that after you are making the network calls to your server you get back on the UI Thread before initializing and calling the SDK.